# Jboss 5 Integration with Apache 2.2

Tags: apache, file, jboss, integration, war

I have successfully integrated Jboss with Apache.  I can pull up http://localhost/web-console .... now when I drop a war file into my Jboss deploy directory I can pull it up here localhost:8080/helloworld/hi.jsp BUT NOT here localhost/helloworld/hi.jsp

Isn't the point of integrating Jboss with apache so I do not have to do :8080? and I can pull up my WAR file though Apache?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: How are you integrating JBoss with Apache: mod_jk, mod_proxy_ajp, ...?

Comment: To me, the point of integrating JBoss with Apache is not just to remove the port from the URL. If this is your only concern, run JBoss on port 80 instead of 8080.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify how you have integrated JBoss with apache, there are several methods.

If you are using mod_jk, you need to add some configuration for apache to realize it needs to forward requests to helloworld to JBoss. You can do this by adding the following to your mod_jk.conf (or whatever the mod_jk configuration file is named in your apache configuration)

JkMount  /helloworld/*  jboss

JkMount  /helloworld    jboss

This does not apply if you are using one of the proxy methods of integrating apache with JBoss.

Comment: The reason for the two JkMount entries is to forward the URI helloworld with and without the trailing slash to JBoss.